# Add maxlength attribute to WordPress post title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there a hook I can use to append a **maxlength** attribute to WordPress post titles? I am familiar with sub string function techniques (e.g. http://www.doc4design.com/articles/wordpress-5ways-shorten-titles/), but that's not the same. I've also seen the [Limit Post Titles](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/limit-post-titles/) plugin which again works well, but still doesn't *enforce* the limit.

I want to **limit the character length from the onset**, e.g.:

`<input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" id="title" value="" size="30" maxlength="60" name="post_title" />`

Having not found anything on this subject, I assume there might be reasoning as to why this is not a good idea? If so, I would be interested in knowing why.

Comment: Did you try this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/limit-post-titles/

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the code, I don't think there is a filter you can hook into the add a `maxlength` attribute to the title field.

You could use javascript to add the attribute:

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
?>
    <script>jQuery('input#title').attr('maxlength', 60);</script>
<?php
});
```

Note that if you really need to *enforce* the limit, the maxlength attribute is not sufficient. It's trivial to bypass the restriction.

You'll also need to use the [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action to validate the title.

> I assume there might be reasoning as to why this is not a good idea

It *is a good idea* to enforce restrictions in the frontend. Letting the user know that their input does not fall within an expected range prior to submitting a form is generally preferable to giving them an error message after submitting the form. You just have to bear in mind that those restrictions must be verified in the backend.

Comment: Thanks @mtinsley, I'll give that a crack!

Answer (score 0):

I used Mathew Tinsley's answer in my project. And I added a message in the title label informing the user of the limit.

```
add_action('admin_footer', function() {
?>
<script>
  jQuery('input#title').attr('maxlength', 60);</script>
  jQuery('label#title-prompt-text').text("Add Title (max 60 characters)");
</script>
<?php
});
```